# I want to solve Mathieu Equation $y''(x)+(a−2q \cos(2x))y(x)=0$. How to solve it using Floquet solution?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-optics, special-functions

I want to solve [Mathieu Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function) $$y''(x)+(a−2q \cos(2x)) \, y(x)=0.$$ How to solve it using [Floquet solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function#Floquet_solution)? In Floquet solution for integer order of $v$ and $π$ periodicity
We have Solution
$$y(x)=\exp(ivx) \, P(x)$$
I want to know what are the $P(x)$?

Comment: Would [Maths SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) be a better home for this question?

Comment: i have tried there too
But no answer

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1304994

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathieu+floquet

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to give a full answer here as this would require to go through a lot of mathematical technicalities (which are in the literature anyhow, see below). As this is a physics site, let me first point out that the Mathieu equation may be viewed, for example, as the Schrödinger equation for a particle in a periodic potential. As such it describes the occurrence of energy bands, relevant for solid state physics.

As the equation is second order, the general solution is actually of the form (allowing for complex argument, $z$)

$$ y(z) = c_1 e^{i\nu z} P(z) + c_2 e^{-i\nu z} P(-z) \; , $$

as long as the Floquet exponent $\nu = \nu (a,q)$ is non-integer. It *does* become integer for certain characteristic values of $a$, the Mathieu eigenvalues $a_n(q)$ and $b_n(q)$. The curves $a = a_n(q)$ and $a = b_n(q)$, corresponding to integer $\nu$, divide the $(q,a)$ plane into regions of stability ($\nu$ real) and instability ($\nu$ complex). In physics terms, these correspond to energy bands and gaps, respectively.

The standard mathematical online resource for the Mathieu equation is [Ch. 28](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28) of the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions. You may also want to look at Ch. 20 of Abramowitz and Stegun, available via its [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun).

The most thorough physics discussion I am aware of is in Ch. 17 of Müller-Kirsten's [Introduction to Quantum Mechanics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-To-Quantum-Mechanics-Schrodinger/dp/9814397741/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). It contains also the weak and strong coupling approximations (small and large $q$, respectively). There has been a very recent renaissance of the Mathieu equation in the context of divergent series and resurgence. The papers [arxiv:1401.5202](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5202) and [arxiv:1502.06680](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06680) contain discussions relevant in this context (and much more), including plots of the stability regions/band structure using Mathematica.

The bottom line is that there is no way of understanding the (physics described by the) Mathieu equation without getting one's hands dirty with the somewhat complicated maths involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur cooperation and time. I am just confused in P(z). 
What will be that?
because its written in literature these are mathieu functions and i just want to know are these MAthieC[a,q,z]+MAthieS[a,q,z]
or something else for integer _v_

Comment: As you seem to be using Maple notation - have you checked the Maple help page (just search for "Mathieu")? The most relevant Mathieu functions are listed there together with their mutual relationships.